Getting [No qualifying bean of type] after adding a 3rd party dependency
While upgrading a dependency, I encountered an issue where the final JAR file generated is throwing an error when installing on OSGI container No qualifying bean of type  'com.atlassian.confluence.core.DataSourceFactory'. However, when I remove or downgrade the dependency to its original version, everything works fine. I am unsure how to proceed in this scenario. Where should I start looking for a solution? Should I contact the third-party dependency provider about this issue? If so, I'm not sure what to ask them to fix, as the same dependency works correctly in a separate codebase.
